# Objects are not emitting light

Tags: objects, light, emission

The 80s sun is not emitting light at all but the pink grid is emitting but not as much as needed even though i put the strength right up.It was emitting fine on the grid but i must have changed something and now not emitting as much. I have got into a mess with this. Thanks. (I've also lost the menu bar in the node editor, it appears again when i render.)

Sun settings
[image]
pink grid settings
[image]
rendered image
[image]
more settings of sun
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you plugging the alpha output of the gradient node into the strength socket of the emission node for the sun material? You could simply adjust the value directly without plugging anything into that socket, like you did in the grid material.

Comment: I didnt mean to plug it to the material , however when i did it gave it the depth of color i was after by accident. (new to blender still:( With it unplugged it does now emit light but looks a different shade, not sure how to replicate what i had before and have it emit. with alpha not connected it looks like the new image above

Comment: thanks i'll try this

Comment: Also, you might think about what's there to _receive_ the light, to give cues that it's being emitted? If it's the atmosphere, you might consider Bloom in EEVEE, or volumetrics in Cycles..